# Complex search in xml using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

**Background** I am trying to read a password from a keepass2 file using [libkeepass](https://github.com/phpwutz/libkeepass) python library.

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (beause that is what libkeepass gives me) I have to search for an entry like this and take the password value from it

```
<Entry>
<String>
    <Key>Password</Key>
    <Value Protected="False" ProtectedValue="XXX">XXX</Value>
</String>
<String>
    <Key>Title</Key>
    <Value>PasswordName</Value>
</Entry>
```

So I have to find an entry:

- with a child "String"

  - with a child "Key" with value "Title"
  - with a child "Value" with value "PasswordName"
- with a child "String"

  - with a child "Key" with value "Password"
  - with a child "Value" -> and the value of that child is what I need

I already got this far (kdb beeing the password file object):

```
kdb.obj_root.findall(".//Entry/String[Key='Title'][Value='PasswordName']")
```

This gives me the String Element of the correct entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, instead of going down to `String`, back up to `Entry` and then down again to another `String`, you can just use predicate on `Entry` element and then return the target `String` element from there.

Since you're using `lxml`, I'd also suggest to use `xpath()` method instead of `findall()`. The former provides full support for XPath 1.0 expression, while the latter only supports [subset of XPath 1.0](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) :

```
query = """
        .//Entry[String[Key='Title' and Value='MyPassword']]
         /String[Key='Password']
         /Value
        """
kdb.obj_root.xpath(query)
```

Comment: Oh, that is how you Nest predicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized, I can navigate up using "..". So the solution is:

```
kdb.obj_root.findall(".//Entry/String[Key='Title'][Value='MyPassword']/../String[Key='Password']/Value")
```